# Find string in text and replace it with one of the list values

Tags: python

My code is

```
my_text=" Mr. [name] [surname] live in [town]"
list1=["[name]","[surname]","[town]"]
list2=["John","Smith","London"]
for x in list1:
    number=list1.index(x)
    mytext2=my_text.replace(x,list2[number])
print(mytext2)
```

The original my_text is read from docx file and it is much longer. 
I would like to automatically find in my_text elements from list1 and replace them  with right elements from list2.
I try to do it with for loop but at the end it worked for the last position only. This code is not working for me.

Comment: have you thought of using something like jinja2?

Answer (score 3):

If u can format the text as below,

```
my_text=" Mr. {name} {surname} live in {town}"

list1=["name","surname","town"]
list2=["John","Smith","London"]

my_text.format(**dict(zip(list1, list2)))

# Mr. John Smith live in London
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with a dictionary lookup more effectively:

```
my_text = " Mr. [name] [surname] live in [town]"
list1 = ["[name]","[surname]","[town]"]
list2 = ["John","Smith","London"]

d = dict(zip(list1, list2))
res = ' '.join([d.get(x, x) for x in my_text.split()])

# Mr. John Smith live in London
```

Comment: @komatiraju032, Thanks, it will not work; but let OP comment on if that's actually a scenario.

Comment: ```import docx2txt


my_text = docx2txt.process("Umowa1.docx")
list1=[" [name]", "[surname]","[town]"]
list2=["zenek", "martyniuk", "London"]
d = dict(zip(list1, list2))
print(' '.join([d.get(x, x) for x in my_text.split()]))``` Your code find and replace first record of the text. Then put it back to strilng in one line. The text is taken from docx file and  let say the docx file has my_text string from the question. In this text I need to replace brackets elements to those from list2. I see that there is important if we have string in my_text or imported string from docx.

Comment: @ConradNiepodam: I'm not really getting your point in the comments. As long as you have `my_text` and is a string, you are good to use this method.

Answer (score 0):

My orginal code is :

```
import docx2txt

def replace_word(first_name,surname,town):
    my_text = docx2txt.process("Umowa1.docx")
    list_of_change=["{first_name}","{surname}","{town}"]
    for x in list_of_change:
        number = list_of_change.index(x)
        z = my_text.replace(x, name)
        print(z)

# Tekst in file .docx to : Mr {first_name} {surname} live in {town}
first_name="Tom"
surname="Smith"
town="London"
replace_word(first_name,surname,town)
```

I would like the function to replace in file Umowa1.docx  strings marked in {} to one from arguments of the function so I have in file output Mr Tom Smith live in London

Comment: as I observe my script in for loop changing string but somehow it not keep changing from previous iteration so in first it change first_name  but in second change surname and first name returning to previous state , So result is that my_text has only last change. I try to put open file above definision of the function but it not help. Maybe I should do some other function instead for loop? By the Way Thank you  Austin for looking into may case!

Comment: THANK you Austin I adapted your solution. My mistake is as there is comas in text from the files and it stick to {surname}, and it is string the program could't find ant this make problem as it is difference between {name} and {name},   !!!

Answer (score 0):

My final Code which is working!

```
import docx2txt


def exchenage_word(first_name,surname,town):
    my_text = docx2txt.process("Umowa1.docx")
    list_to_change=["{first_name}","{surname},","{town}."]
    new_list=[first_name,surname,town]
    d = dict(zip(list_to_change, new_list))
    res = ' '.join([d.get(x, x) for x in my_text.split()])
    print(res)
first_name="John"
surname= "Smith"
town="Londyn"
exchange_word(first_name,surname,town)
# the text in Umowa1.docx is: Mr {first_name} {surname}, live in {town}.
```